# How to open an activity after clicking on a menu item?

Tags: java, android, menu

How do you open a new activity when you click on an item in the menu list?

For example I have a menu item named "Teams" so after I click on that, the "TeamsActivity" should open. I've searched on the internet but that didn't help me.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
                   ???????????????????
        case R.id.Teams:
                   ???????????????????
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you create an Intent and start it. 
You can have a look in the tutorial of the [developer-site of android.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

In your case it's something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
                   intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                   break;
        case R.id.Teams:
                   intent = new Intent(this, TeamsActivity.class);
                   break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```